# How to add characters to ckeditor in Savvy CMS

Tags: ckeditor, coldfusion-9

I have run into a problem adding special characters to the CKEditor 4 in a Savvy CMS installation. For example, the Turkish characters: `ğ`, `ı`, and `ş` represented by entity codes: `&#287;`, `&#305;`, and `&#351;` are stripped out of the rich text when the content object is published.

**Unpublished**
[image]

**Published**
[image]

The HTML markup is as follows

```
<style>
  td{width:50px;padding:5px;text-align:center;background-color:#e0e0e0;}
</style>

<p>The Turkish alphabet is a modified version of the Latin alphabet and consists of 29 letters.<br/>
Included are 6 additional letters...</p>

<table>
  <tr>
   <td>&#231;</td>
   <td>&#287;</td>
   <td>&#305;</td>
   <td>&#246;</td>
   <td>&#351;</td>
   <td>&#252;</td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <p>...while - q, w, x - are excluded.</p>
```

I located the config.js file for the CKEditor and appended the entity codes as follows

```
config.specialChars = ['!', '&quot;'... '&#287;', '&#305;'...];
```

I also tried

```
config.extraSpecialChars = ['&#287;'];
```

However, the special characters are still stripped when the object is published.
How can I configure the CKEditor 4 to accept additional special characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead

```
config.entities_additional = '#287,#305,#351';
```